# Rails - psql deploy on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, psql

I have a rails 4 app on heroku with a PSQL database.

This has all been fine in development, but I'm coming to my first attempt at publishing the app with content in the database.

I recently reset the database locally and in heroku. And also did:

```
heroku ran rake:db migrate
```

I then created the first article in my articles resource and committed, pushed and pushed to heroku. I expected to see that article displayed (as it is in my local host).

However, when I go on local host in production mode or to the published site, the article is not there.

Is there a step I'm missing for how to push to heroku with the db content you want? Is there something that needs to be done to make the production database recognise the development database? Not sure about the steps for publishing the production db.

In my database.yml file I have:

```
staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: vh_staging
  pool: 5
  #username: vh

  #host: localhost

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: vh_development
  pool: 5
  #username: vh

test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: vh_test
  pool: 5
  #username: vh

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: vh_production
  pool: 5
  #username: vh
```

Comment: Try running `heroku logs` in the terminal, and see what comes up.

Comment: it renders all the views and checks the login status. There is no mention of the db in the logs. Should there be?

Answer (score 0):

You push on heroku only your code, not a database data.

Comment: how do you get it to recognise db data?

Comment: may be article can help you https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku

Comment: db:push is not a valid heroku command. looking further into other things to try. my heroku account recognises the db attached - but not sure what needs to be done to get it to sync

Answer (score 0):

Try doing that by `seed`:

```
heroku run rake db:push
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run rake db:seed
```

You should have your data as ruby code in your the file `db/seeds.ru` to do that.